# sum distinct value while using distinct id

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am working on a data  that looks like this:

[image: sample_data]

from the table the gender (M,F) has the same globalid, however, I need to sum the distinct globalid's value column based on the gender (total from M and F).
I have tried this code but the query just returned the same data.

```
select distinct (globalid) globalid, fcname, featureidentifier, 
       gender, source, wardcode,sum (distinct value) 
from public.kano_pp 
  source= 'Worldpop / ORNL Adjusted' 
group by globalid, fcname, featureidentifier,gender, source, wardcode, value
order by globalid;
```

Comment: did you mean to write `distinct ON (globalid)`? You are also missing a `where` clause

Comment: i needed to sum the distinct 'globalid'  on the value 'column'

Comment: Well the query as written is invalid. It's either `distinct on (globalid) globalid, fcname...` or simply `distinct globalid, fcname, ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want something more like this:

```
select globalid,
       sum(case when gender = 'F' then value else 0 end) as female_value,
       sum(case when gender = 'M' then value else 0 end) as male_value
from public.kano_pp 
where source = 'Worldpop / ORNL Adjusted' 
group by globalid
order by globalid;
```

The more recent versions of Postgres support the `filter` clause which is a bit more efficient than the `sum(case . .  )`.